# GLMM failure to converge warning

Tags: r, convergence, glmm

I built a generalized linear mixed model using the code:

```
detect_global <- glmer(outcome ~ season*year + season*sex + sex*year + (1 | obsname) + (1 | bird), 
     data = detect, 
     family = binomial)
```

Season is a 3-level factor (molting, breeding, and winter), year is a 3-level factor (2019, 2020, and 2021), sex is a 2-level factor, and obsname and bird are random effects. Bird is a 4-letter ID for each bird in the study (~50), and obsname is an ID for each observer in the study (5). Each bird was sample a minimum of 25 times.

Then, I used the MuMIn::dredge function to produce a list of all possible models, ranked by AICc. However, I receive this warning when I run the code:

```
Warning in checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00204414 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

If I include main effects only and get rid of the interactions, this warning disappears. If I run a model with interactions but exclude bird as a random effect, the warning also disappears. Does that mean I have to run main effects only or exclude bird, or is there a way to correct this?

Comment: [Here are some answers.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Model+failed+to+converge%22+glm*+answers%3A1)  As a general proposition, procedures that automatically include large numbers of variables or posit large numbers of models in a search tend to turn up instances that are unstable.  This can happen even with huge datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to fit a model with the same variance-covariance structure using generalized estimating equations (GEE).  Perhaps this method will converge for your full model and its inadequacies can be tested (i.e. inclusion of fixed-effect or variance component terms that are insignificant or overparametrizing the model).  Perhaps a GLM could also be run initially to test for the significance of the interaction terms in your fixed-effects.  Additionally, maybe the frequency of certain pairs of covariates is too small to give a reasonable estimate.